# Can't remove tapped spriteNode using removeFromParent : Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a for-loop that instantiates 5 sprites as such

```
for enemy in 1...5 {
    negativeOnComing = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy3")
    negativeOnComing.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: negativeOnComing.frame.size.width/2)
    negativeOnComing.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    negativeOnComing.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.negativeOncoming
    negativeOnComing.physicsBody?.fieldBitMask = PhysicsCategory.negativeOncoming
    negativeOnComing.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.mainCenterNode | PhysicsCategory.positiveOncoming
    negativeOnComing.physicsBody?.node?.name = "negativeOnComing"
self.addChild(negativeOnComing)
```

}
I already declared the variable globally as

```
var negativeOnComing : SKSpriteNode!
```

Now I want to be able to remove the sprite thats been tapped on once tapped. To attempt this I did

```
 func removeNegativeOncoming(negativeOnComingR:SKSpriteNode){
    println("Tapped")
    childNodeWithName("negativeOnComing")?.removeFromParent()
       }


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){
    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var touchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var enemyNodePosition = negativeOnComing.childNodeWithName("negativeOnComing")?.position
    var enemyNodeFrame = negativeOnComing.frame
   func removeEnemyNode (UITouch) -> SKSpriteNode {
        if (enemyNodeFrame.contains(touchPosition) ) {
            removeNegativeOncoming(negativeOnComing)
        }
        return negativeOnComing
    }
    mainSpriteMovement(touch)

}
```

Now this function in fact does remove the sprite however , it DOES NOT remove the sprite that was exactly tapped on but just one of the 5 sprites at random. My question is how can I have the sprite only that was tapped on to me removed and not just and random one of the 5. Hopefully this question was well asked and understandable. THANK YOU ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating 5 enemies, but setting `negativeOnComing` each time, so this variable will only end up holding a reference to the last node created.

This isn't the cause of your problem, however.  You are using `childNodeWithName` to find the node to remove - but all of your enemy nodes have the same name, so you get one at random.

You can simply use `nodeAtPoint` to determine which node was tapped -

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){
    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var touchPosition = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchPosition)
    if (touchedNode.name == "negativeOnComing") {
        touchedNode.removeFromParent()
    }
    mainSpriteMovement(touch)

}
```

Comment: Yes!! This did the trick, Im thankful to be in a community of such talented developers! Thank You